# How to avoid writing php notices and warnings in log files?

Tags: php, warnings

Is there anyway to avoid writing notices and warnings in php log files? I want fatal error and parse errors to be written, but I want to avoid writing notices and warnings since the size of the logs grow larger.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to avoid them from being written is to simply check the warnings and notices that are currently logged and to simply **fix** the issues. If you're concerned that the log size is getting too large as a result of these warnings and notices, they must be getting logged very frequently in which case ignoring them probably isn't a good idea.

After all, that's what the logs are for. Your code will be better as a result, and you'll no longer be sticking your head in the sand and ignoring what is still an issue in your project.