# PHP - How to suppress individual warnings in error log file?

Tags: php

My script scrapes data from a web site. Whenever that web site isn't available, I get an error like this in my **error_log** file:

> [03-Jun-2017 15:00:03 UTC] PHP Warning:  file(http://example.com):
>   failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 503 Service
>   Unavailable

There's a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27618010/how-to-avoid-writing-php-notices-and-warnings-in-log-files), but I am only wanting to suppress *individual* warning - as I would like any other warnings from my script to still be logged.

So is it possible to suppress warnings from individual lines?

I have tried surrounding the line of code that gives a warning in a try/catch block - i.e.,

```
try {
    $lines = file("https://example.com"); // This line results in a warning in my error_log file if the web page is currently unavailable
}
catch(Exception $e) {
}
```

but I still get the warning. Does anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: try use this: `error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);` Its because warning is not exception => you cant catch it. I recommends have warnings turned off in production....

Comment: Thanks, but wouldn't that suppress all other warnings (which I want to keep)?

Comment: yes next nasty option is this: `@file("https://example.com");`
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Comment: What if I moved my `$lines = file("https://example.com");` line of code to a separate php file and then set `error_reporting(...)` in that file only. Could that work?

Comment: I would use @ operator and after that check if there is any content in `$lines`

Comment: Thanks, but I'll keep away from that one if it's a quick and dirty fix.

Answer (score 1):

Suppressing errors is nonsense in almost every case. A proper solution would be checking for the returned HTTP Status code and only if it is valid - use file on it.

For example(not tested, 3v4l sadly doesn't support cURL):

```
<?php
    function checkDomain($domain) {
        $handle = curl_init($url);
        $success = true;
        curl_setopt($handle,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

        /* Get the HTML or whatever is linked in $url. */
        $response = curl_exec($handle);

        /* Check for 404 (file not found). */
        $httpCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        if($httpCode == 503) {
            $success = false;
        }


        curl_close($handle);
        return $success;
    }

    $domain = 'http://www.goweogweog.de';
    if(checkDomain($domain)) { // GOOD
        file($domain);
    }

    file($domain); // BAD
```

Comment: OK, thanks. Is it possible to check the HTTP status code without making an additional request?

Comment: @ban-geoengineering Yes - stop using file() to handle url's and their responses and use curl to get the response.

Comment: Thanks, but even if I add `curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);` to your code, I am still making two requests - one via **cURL** and one via `file($domain)`. Is it possible to do the check and (if code 200) the retrieval with a single call?

Comment: @ban-geoengineering Yes as I said - stop using `file()` at all - use `$response = curl_exec($handle)` and parse the output properly.

Comment: Could you update your code accordingly as it seems to be using both at the moment?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can toggle the error reporting status in the script:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); // Report all errors/warnings/notices
$lines = file("https://111111asegfiwaehflewakfhewaflk.err"); // Warning logged

error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE); // Don't report warnings
$lines = file("https://222222asegfiwaehflewakfhewaflk.err"); // Warning NOT logged

error_reporting(E_ALL); // Report all errors/warnings/notices
$lines = file("https://333333asegfiwaehflewakfhewaflk.err"); // Warning logged
```

[Xatenev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44499091/1617737) is a better approach, but am posting this answer as it answers the original question.